# ggplot error bars on a barplot have the wrong position

Tags: r, ggplot2

When I generate the graph using the following code, the error bars are in strange positions.  Can you tell me how to get the error bars to show up around the top of each bar in the barchart?  I know this is basic, but I've been staring at it for hours now.  Thanks.

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(gender=c("male","male","female","female"),
             trait=c("height","weight","height","weight"),
             value=c(70,150,65,120),
             sd = c(5,15,4,10))

gg <- ggplot(df,aes(x=trait,y=value,fill=trait))
gg <- gg+ geom_bar(stat="identity",position=position_dodge())
gg <- gg + facet_wrap(~ gender, ncol=1)

limits <- aes(ymax=df$value+df$sd, ymin=df$value-df$sd)                                                                                               
gg <- gg + geom_errorbar(limits)
#gg <- gg + geom_pointrange(limits)                                                                                                                                                                       
gg
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get strange position of errorbars because you use `df$value` in setting of postion (it makes position the same). You should set position in `aes()` just as `value-sd` (without `df$`) and you can set `ymin` and `ymax` inside `ggplot()` call.

```
ggplot(df,aes(x=trait,y=value,fill=trait,ymin=value-sd,ymax=value+sd))+
       geom_bar(stat="identity",position=position_dodge())+
       facet_wrap(~ gender, ncol=1)+
       geom_errorbar()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Didzis.  You saved me a lot of time.